# How do you submit form content without inputs with inline TinyMCE editor?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, tinymce, tinymce-4

Here's how they tell you to do it in the docs.

```
  <form method="post" action="process.php">
    <div class="wysiwyg">Click here to edit the first section of content!</div>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Then in the head of the document:

```
tinymce.init({ selector: '.wysiwyg',
        inline: true,
etc...
```

But I need to assign a name to the content of the div so my php processing page can get the content. How would I do this?

I tried to change to the get method, and it seems to use "mce_0" as a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it manually, for example, put an id to your `wysiwyg`

```
<div id="my-wysiwyg" class="wysiwyg">Click here to edit the content!</div>
```

then get the value

```
var txt = $('#my-wysiwyg').html();
```

then make a post manually

```
$.post('my.php', {wysiwyg: txt}, function onSuccess(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Then, in your php, you will get a `name` wysiwyg. This is just an illustrative example of how you can do it, adapt to your context.

[Check this out.](http://developertips.net/tinymce-inline-editing-w-jqueryajax-php/)
Hope it helps